# Unwanted space in row table for signature html

Tags: html, row, padding, signature, css-tables

I'm making an email signature for my boss. So I upload the signature in my website and make him copy it and just paste it in his MS Outlook. In the html the signature looks fine when I try to test it, it also looks fine BUT when he's pasting it in his Outlook there's this unwanted space between the image and the text.

Here's how it's supposed to look:

[image: This is how it looks on the web and in my outlook]

Here's how it's turning out on his:

[image: Unwanted space in between logo and text]

Here's my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <style>
      body {
        font-size:12px;
        font-family:  Arial;
      }
      /*table, td, th {
          border: 1px solid black;
      }*/

      table {
          width: 580px;
      }

      th {
          text-align: left;
      }
      p {
        font-size:10px;
      }
      </style>
      </head>
      <body>

      <h2>Highlight + Copy + Paste</h2>

      <table cellpading="0" cellspacing="0">

        <tr>
          <td rowspan="5" width="194px"><img style="display:block; border-collapse:collapse;" src="image.png"></td>
          <td colspan="2" style="font-size:18px; padding:5px"><b>Name</b><br>
            <span style="font-size:12px"><i>V.P. of Business Development</i></span></td>

        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td width="150px" style="padding:5px;"><img src="http://i795.photobucket.com/albums/yy239/spacebitss/phone.jpg">+000000000</td>
          <td><img src="http://i795.photobucket.com/albums/yy239/spacebitss/fax.jpg"> +000000000</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="padding:5px;"><img src="http://i795.photobucket.com/albums/yy239/spacebitss/mail.jpg"> email</td>
          <td><img src="http://i795.photobucket.com/albums/yy239/spacebitss/cell.jpg"> +000000000</td>
      </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="padding:5px;"><img src="http://i795.photobucket.com/albums/yy239/spacebitss/skype.jpg"> skype</td>
          <td><img src="http://i795.photobucket.com/albums/yy239/spacebitss/web.jpg"> website</td>

      </tr>
        <tr style="padding:5px;">
           <td colspan="2"><img src="http://i795.photobucket.com/albums/yy239/spacebitss/add.jpg"> address          </td>

      </tr>
      </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="3"><p style="color:gray;">This message is only for the use of the person(s) for whom it is intended. It may contain confidential information.<br> 
      The unauthorized use, copying, distribution, or disclosure of this e-mail or any of its contents by anyone other than the intended recipient is unauthorized and unlawful. 
      If you have received this e-mail in error, please notify the sender immediately and destroy all copies of this transmission. 
      Thank you.  <br> <span style="color:green; font-size:11px;"><img src="http://i795.photobucket.com/albums/yy239/spacebitss/tree.png"> Please think of the environment before you consider printing this e-mail</span></p>  
      </td>

      </tr>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is :

1. Duplicated (you have the same signature twice).
2. Contains non-standard attributes.
3. Contains non standard attribute values.

In other word, I doubt anyone will attempt to fix this code for you. What I would suggest is that you start from scratch using tools such as this:

- https://www.exclaimer.ca/email-signature-creator/
- https://htmlsig.com/
- [Etc](https://www.google.com/?q=outlook%20signature%20creator).